# Add a paragraph in File

Tags: java, api, io

I would like to write a paragraph using file.

This is my code(my effort).

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main (String [] args) 
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {

            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:/Users/Akram/Documents/akram.txt")) ;
            System.out.println("Write the Text in the File ");
            String str  = input.nextLine();
            out.write(str);
            out.close();
            System.out.println("File created successfuly");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

With this code I can add just one word but I want to add a lot of word (paragraph).

Comment: nextLine() should give you the entire content from your input till a new line character (\n). Your paragraph contains new line characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a `while` loop around [`Scanner#hasNextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine%28%29). I would also recommend a [`PrintWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html). So, all together, that would look something like,

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
PrintWriter out = null;
try {
    out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(
            "C:/Users/Akram/Documents/akram.txt"));
    System.out.println("Write the Text in the File ");
    while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        String str = input.nextLine();
        out.println(str);
    }
    System.out.println("File created successfuly");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (out != null) {
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to write a paragraph, Decide a terminating character or string,Write your code so that it takes the input till that character or string is given in the input, Do some operation to remove the character in the file,
The code which I used is given below,Terminating Character is +
I haven't kept try and catch statements to reduce complexity in understanding

```
    pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("E://files//myfile.txt"));   
    System.out.println("Write the Text in the File,End the text with + ");
    do
    {
        Scanner sc =new Scanner(System.in);
        String S=sc.nextLine();
        if(S.endsWith("+"))
        {
           S= S.replace("+"," ");
            flag=1;
            pw.println(S);
        }
        else
            pw.println(S); 
    }while(flag!=1);
```

Cheers